# Joining Tables: case statement for no matches?

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.text,se.name,s.sub_name,SUM((p.volume / (SELECT SUM(p.volume) 
                FROM phrase p
                WHERE p.volume IS NOT NULL) * sp.position))
AS `index`
FROM phrase p
LEFT JOIN `position` sp ON sp.phrase_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN `engines` se ON se.id = sp.engine_id
LEFT JOIN item s ON s.id = sp.site_id
WHERE p.volume IS NOT NULL
AND s.ignored = 0
GROUP BY se.name,s.sub_name
ORDER BY se.name,s.sub_name
```

There are a few things I want to do with it:

1) The end of the calculation for `'index'`, I multiple it all by sp.position, then get it's SUM. If there is NO MATCH in the first LEFT JOIN `'position'`, I want to give sp.position a value of 200. So basically if in the `'phrase'` table I have an ID=2, but that does not exist in sp.phrase_id in the entire `'position'` table, then sp.position=200 for the `'index'` calculation, otherwise it will it will be whatever value is stored in the `'position'` table. I hope that makes sense.

2) I do a GROUP BY se.name. I would like to actually SUM the entire `'index'` values for similar se.name fields. So in the resultset as it stands now, if there were 20 p.text rows with the same se.name, I would like to SUM the index column for the same se.name(s).

I am more of a PHP guy, but trying to learn more MySQL. I have become a big believer in making the DB do as much of the work as possible instead of trying to manipulate the dataset after it's been returned.

I hope the questions were clear. Anyways, can both 1) and 2) be done? There's much more I want to modify this query to do, but I think if I need more help in the future on it, it would require a different question.

The position table has a engines_id, phrase_id, item_id which will make it a unique entry. The value I am trying to calculate is the sp.position value. But there are cases when there is no entry for these IDs combined. If there is no entry for the combo of 3 IDs I just listed, I would like to use sp.position=200 in my calculation.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but COALESCE() will return the first non-NULL parameter passed to it: "SELECT COALESCE(sp.position, 200) FROM ..." will return 200 when sp.position is NULL.  Either way, +1 for "making the DB do as much of the work as possible."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
select x.name, sum(index) from
(
SELECT p.text,se.name,s.sub_name,SUM((p.volume / (SELECT SUM(p.volume) 
            FROM phrase p
            WHERE p.volume IS NOT NULL) * if(sp.position is null,200,sp.position)))
AS `index`
FROM phrase p
LEFT JOIN `position` sp ON sp.phrase_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN `engines` se ON se.id = sp.engine_id
LEFT JOIN item s ON s.id = sp.site_id
WHERE p.volume IS NOT NULL
AND s.ignored = 0
GROUP BY se.name,s.sub_name
ORDER BY se.name,s.sub_name
 )x
GROUP BY x.name
```

Comment: I am going to try this tomorrow, but on that INNER SELECT query, Looking at the IF statement it makes sense, but the sp.position field in the position table will never be NULL. It will only have an INT in that column, or the record will not exist. Should I do some sort of OUTER JOIN, so it returns every possible instance? NULL or not? Basically like a list of every item in the phrase table * the engines table. If there is a corresponding record in the position table that has a matching phrase.id and engines.id, the use that sp.position otherwise, 200.

Comment: To explain a bit more. the there is a phrase_id and engines_id (FKs) in the position table, that link to the phrase and engines table. And I only INSERT into position table if I have a position for that phrase_id and engines_id. If not, I don't store it. BUT, for reporting purposes on this project, I have decided to set the number 200 as the position for phrase / engines id's I don't have data on. 

Thanks for your help. I look forward to finishing this up tomorrow morning!

Comment: You're doing a left join onto position, so it looks to me like that field will be null for any phrase record that doesn't have a match in the position table

Comment: When I run the inner query, I am getting data back, But I have 3 entrys in the engines table, so I would think I would have 3 rows for every p.text b/c I have 3 entries in the engines table. But if I only have one entry that matches: (item s, phrase p, engines se) in the position sp table, it only returns 1 row, instead of 3 rows, so it doesn't look like this is happening: if(sp.position is null,200,sp.position)

Should I try a UNION on phrase p and position sp? I am updating the main post with how the position table is

Comment: Looking more at LEFT JOIN. You are right, it should show a NULL. I will dig deeper as to why it hasn't

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1.) Use `IFNULL()`, in your case `IFNULL(sp.position, 200)`

2.) I am not entirely clear on this part, but it seems like you already have part of what you are asking.